# Multiple robots with ROS-I / ABB driver

Tags: ros, abb, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have the abb_drivers running a single ABB IRB 120 and I'm trying to get both of them online. There is a footnote in the installServer tutorial saying "For multi-robot controllers, specify the desired robot (e.g. rob1) for each task" but that doesn't make new rostopics for the different robots to communicate through. How do I make multiple robots work with this driver? I don't see a clear place where I can change the topic names in ROS so that the robots can be commanded.

I have tried renaming all the files Rob1/2 at the end and updating the inside, but it kind of blows up on me very quickly and doesn't seem like it will work on the ROS side.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243975/multiple-robots-with-ros-i-/-abb-driver/) by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8272 on 2016-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've commented on [ros-industrial/abb#106](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb/issues/106).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2016-09-19**:
Thanks for the response. I meant to link that here as well and forgot. I'll report back here with any files I created to help any future people.